# Activating my locked iPhone after wrong passcode

Tags: ios, ipad

I can't use my iPhone any longer after my son wrongly entered my passcode to unlock my phone and I am finding it difficult to activate it after his action. How can I get it working again?

Comment: "Activate it", as in with a carrier or just turning the iPhone on?

Comment: i want to enable my iphone is has been disabled after some tries in unlocking the passcode

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in order to restore an iPhone that was disabled by failed passcode attempts, you will lose all data. Anyways, here's the [article](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+4+-+4S+-+5+-+5S+-+5c+-+how+to+flash+from+DFU+mode.+Password+recovery./28229) which shows how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Apple article: [If you forgot the passcode for your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, or your device is disabled](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306)

Reset video: [RESET PASSCODE locked or disabled iPhone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LsSu2ddzqw)